# App won't load with sandboxing enabled

Tags: xcode, entitlements, appstore-sandbox

I have an app which is accessing a SQLite database and some other data files from within its bundle. Other than that, there is no filesystem, network, or hardware access.  When I turn on entitlements and sandbox my app, it won't start. I hit play in Xcode, which shows the app is running, but no window shows, and no output is logged to the debugging console in Xcode.

How can I go about figuring out what is breaking?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to open up **Console.app** and filter by the text `sandboxd` to see what messages are being logged. They won't show up in Xcode's console. You should read up on the [App Sandbox documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH1-SW1), though, if that doesn't work. It's pretty comprehensive documentation for sandboxing.